# Webpack-dev-server issue with hot replacement of entry point

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an issue with webpack, specifically with the hot reload functionality. I am making use of the webpack-dev-server library for this. It is working brilliantly for all javascript files except for the entry point, which for some strange reason is not being hot-replaced automatically. Below is the webpack.config.js file that I am using. Any help is appreciated as we are currently lost.

**Webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/hello.js", "./src/scss/custom.scss"],
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    watchContentBase: true
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      title: 'My Awesome application',
      header: 'Hello World',
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html' //relative to root of the application
  }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { context: './src/scripts/', from: '**/*.html', to: './' },
 { context: './src/', from: 'assets/*', to: './' },
  ]),
       new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          {
            // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },    
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the issue myself. Basically the was two conflicting steps which were overriding each other's results. The culprit step was the CopyWebpackPlugin step, specifically the one copying the assets. This was overriding the index.js file in the dist folder with an older version of itself somehow. Not entirely sure from where this older file was coming from, but once I qualified the step as indicated below, the issue was fixed.

```js
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
   { context: "./src/scripts/", from: "**/*.html", to: "./" },
   { from: "./src/assets", to: "assets" }
]),
```